# Convert object to integer in hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable

```
class Ülke : IComparable<Ülke>
{
    public string ülke; 
    public int nüfus ;
    public int sıra;
}
```

i added objects to my hashtable
   but output is Console.Application ...
   how can i convert object to int
   foreach doesn't work

```
     hashtable.Add(ülke.ülke, ülke);

     foreach (DictionaryEntry i in hashtable)
       {
           if (i.Value is object)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(" " + i.Value);
           }
       }
```

the answer is :

```
  foreach (DictionaryEntry i in hashtable)
        {
            if (i.Value is Ülke)
            {
                Ülke x = (Ülke)i.Value;
                Console.WriteLine(" " + x.ülke + " " + x.nüfus);
            }
        }
```

Comment: everything derives from object... so this isnt helpful. what are you trying to achieve here? what exactly are you storing?

Comment: i added my class object     in my class i have integers

Comment: Vote to close: *unclear what you're asking*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry i in hashtable)
{
   if (i.Value is Ülke)
   {
       Ülke x = (Ülke)i.Value;
       Console.WriteLine(" " + x.Ülke + " " + x.nüfus);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the originally stored item was of type Integer, you can just cast it to (Integer) and just use it as you would an int (Java will autounbox it for you).

`Console.WriteLine(" " + (Integer)(i).Key + " " + i.Value);`

You are taking a risk here, because if you didn't store an Integer, you will get a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator is or try to convert your object to string/int/etc explicitly. But it isn't good practice - to use Hashtable. You should use generic types like Dictionary .